# Disable SELECT until previous SELECT has been picked

Tags: jquery, select

I have 5 HTML select boxes that are all populated with the same data, so not a "chained select".

I want to have select2 disabled until select1 has been picked and select 3 disabled until SELECTS 1 & 2 have been picked, etc.

My SELECT IDs are:

- primary (1)
- record1 (2)
- record2 (3)
- record3 (4)
- record4 (5)

The default value of all the SELECTS is "Select Job"

If a SELECT has ANY OTHER value than "Select Job" then the next SELECT in line can become active.

Not really sure how to do this in jQuery

Comment: This is a famous question on SO

Comment: @refhat: Yet only viewed 18 times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which is independent of how they appear on the page. It could be simplified if the select boxes are always sure to appear in the correct order. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JXGe/4/)

```
var linkOrder = [
    "primary",
    "record1",
    "record2",
    "record3",
    "record4"
];
$('select.linked').not('#' + linkOrder[0]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.linked').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var index = $.inArray(id, linkOrder);
    $('#' + linkOrder[index+1]).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and I like the flexibility. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that all but the first are already disabled:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== "select job") {
        $(this).next("select").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        if(!$(this).index() === 0)
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);   
        $(this).next("select").prop("disabled", true);        
    }
});​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/Z8cSp/3/)

I would normally suggest reading the brilliant resource that is http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ first but I'm waiting for the next bus so I need something to do to kill time (that's not work work).

Comment: Edited to incorporate advanced state maintenance technology.

Comment: @Karim, do I need to clear out my ID's and Names for each SELECT? Looking at your example on JSFiddle I see you just declare the SELECT but dont assign any unique names or IDs?

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx - It's up to you. My solution is based on the relative positions of each select element in the DOM, and as you can see, there are not IDs. You might need them for other stuff though (CSS, other JS, etc)